# Can't access R.layout.mylayoutname in my custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater, custom-adapter

I'm trying to create a custom adapter for my Categories list. For some reason I can't access my category_item layout when I'm trying to inflate it. Here's my code:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    List<Category> list;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Category> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    list = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        convertView=mInflater.inflate(***resource***, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

    }

    return convertView;
}

// Declaring new class ViewHolder
class ViewHolder{
    TextView category_name;
}
```

Where it says `resource` I should be able to access to my category_item.xml layout - R.layout.category_item. But for some reason I don't see it in the list, I can't access it. In the matter of fact I don't see any of my layouts in the list.

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Check if you have the correct (or any at all) R.java imported

Comment: add here line where you are calling adapter in Activity class.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn Yes, apparently I had the wrong R class imported. Have no idea how it happened... Thank you! As you were first to answer my question, can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to just accept any other's correct answer :) Good luck

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Import your `packagename.R` file and it will work. It may be possiblity that you imported `android.R`. As you resource exists in you application package, just correct it and it will work.

android.R refers to sdk resources.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that you imported android resources package `android.R`

Make sure you imported your package resources `com.yourpackagename.R`. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check you code i think you have imported `android.R` in your code. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Project -> Clean
This regenerates that R file and this should work also.